# find all subsets of an integer collection that sums to n

Tags: clojure, combinatorics

i'm trying to find a function that, given S a set of integer and I an integer, return all the subsets of S that sum to I

is there such a function somewhere in clojure-contrib or in another library ?

if no, could anyone please give me some hints to write it the clojure way?

Comment: Is this an interview question? I've heard that this question is being asked quite frequently in Clojure interviews these days.

Comment: @DNNX it's related with a 4clojure.com problem "Sum Some Set Subsets" http://www.4clojure.com/problem/131

Comment: no, not an interview...

Answer (score 4):

I think it is the subset sum problem, as @MrBones suggests.  Here's a brute force attempt using  https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics (lein: `[org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.0.7"]`):

```
(require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as c])

(defn subset-sum [s n] 
  "Return all the subsets of s that sum to n."
  (->> (c/subsets s)
       (filter #(pos? (count %))) ; ignore empty set since (+) == 0
       (filter #(= n (apply + %)))))

(def s #{1 2 45 -3 0 14 25 3 7 15})

(subset-sum s 13)
; ((1 -3 15) (2 -3 14) (0 1 -3 15) (0 2 -3 14) (1 2 3 7) (0 1 2 3 7))
(subset-sum s 0)
; ((0) (-3 3) (0 -3 3) (1 2 -3) (0 1 2 -3))
```

These "subsets" are just lists.  Could convert back to sets, but I didn't bother.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), a classic NP-complete problem?

In which case, I'd just generate every possible distinct subset of S, and see which subsets sums to I.

Comment: Improve efficiency by adding a filter to reject subsets once the sum exceeds I.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the subsets of a set like this:

```
(defn subsets [s]
  (if (seq s)
    (let [f (first s), srs (subsets (disj s f))]
      (concat srs (map #(conj % f) srs)))
    (list #{})))
```

The idea is to choose an element from the set `s`: the first, `f`, will do. Then we recursively find the subsets of everything else, `srs`. `srs` comprises all the subsets without `f`. By adding `f` to each of them, we get all the subsets with `f`. And together, that's the lot. Finally, if we can't choose an element because there aren't any, the only subset is the empty one.

All that remains to do is to filter out from all the subsets the ones that sum to `n`. A function to test this is

```
(fn [s] (= n (reduce + s)))
```

It is not worth naming.

Putting this together, the function we want is

```
(defn subsets-summing-to [s n]
  (filter
    (fn [xs] (= n (reduce + xs)))
    (subsets s)))
```

Notes

- Since the answer is a sequence of sets, we can make it lazier by changing `concat` into `lazy-cat`. `map` is lazy anyway.
- We may appear to be generating a lot of sets, but remember that they share storage: the space cost of keeping another set differing by a single element is (almost) constant.
- The empty set sums to zero in Clojure arithmetic.